# phpMyAdmin issue with proven mysql query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, sleep

This query runs great from a .sql file executed from linux cli. When I execute it from  phpmyadmin, it starts a sleep process, and the http daemon on the server goes to 99% cpu usage, a few minutes later the query fails due to an "internal server error". Any ideas?

```
 INSERT INTO Balance(id, Bal)
        SELECT a.id, SUM(a.Amount)
        FROM(
            SELECT ct.id, SUM(ct.Charges) as Amount
                FROM ChargesT ct
                GROUP BY ct.id  
        UNION ALL
            SELECT pt.id, -SUM(pt.PaymentAmt) as Amount
                FROM PaymentsT pt
                GROUP BY pt.id
            ) a
        GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: How long does the query take, when ran from CLI?

Comment: @MarcDelisle Seconds, almost instant.

Comment: Technically I do not see why you need to sum the charges and payment amounts in the subquery as the outer summation and grouping will do it all for you. In fact you may be able to write this without a subquery which would substantially improve performance

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the summation in the subquery. I think you can probably do it in one query but here's a start

```
 INSERT INTO Balance(id, Bal)
    SELECT a.id, SUM(a.Amount)
    FROM(
        SELECT ct.id, ct.Charges as Amount
            FROM ChargesT ct
        UNION ALL
        SELECT pt.id, -pt.PaymentAmt as Amount
            FROM PaymentsT pt
        ) a
    GROUP BY a.id
```

Comment: some payments are already negative amounts in the PaymentAmt table, credits, so if i sum after the sub query it makes it wrong